# Facebook Unity plugin, cant extend access token or set session log in behaviour

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I am choosing to use the facebook plug in over the Prime31 and I like it so far, however I am quickly noticing two problems:

1. I don't see a method to set the session log in behavior, if I want to force web view I can't find an option to do that.
2. I want to extend the access token, I know I can make a call to do so, however I see that the FB.accessToken has only a get. There is no way to set the access token with the new extended token.

My understanding at this point is that if I don't extend the access token, the user will have to log back in every couple hours. Is this wrong?

**EDIT**

It turns out that any login calls from a mobile sdk are given an extended access token by default.

> "Mobile apps that use Facebook's mobile SDKs get long-lived tokens."

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: Your edit is correct.  The mobile apps are given token that can last for months.

Comment: What about the session log in behaviour?

Comment: There isn't a method to set the session log in behavior.  If I recall correctly, it'll try to do a login natively if it's there, otherwise use the Facebook app, otherwise it'll fallback to launching a browser.  Let us know if there's any reason why you need to use one over another.

Comment: When you say launching a browser do you mean the web view? What is the flow for iOS? Previously if I didn't have 'force web view' set as the session log in behaviour it would try to log the user in through safari if the facebook app was not installed, which is an  ugly process.

Comment: Yes, it'll try to launch the default browser to log the user in if they don't have the facebook app on their device.